# remove outliers from a 2D list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
t = [{k: 1, 'a': 22, 'b': 59}, {k: 2, 'a': 21, 'b': 34}, {'k': 3, 'a': 991, 'b': 29}, {'k': 4, 'a': 45, 'b': 11}, {'k': 5, 'a'; 211, 'b': 77}, {'k': 6, 'a': 100, 'b': 1024}]
```

How do I remove outliers from it so that I can have everything that is centered around some meaningful value or it doesnt have values which are way too large or small?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify what "meaningful" is.  Generally all numbers are meaningful until proven otherwise.

Comment: maybe you could define "way too large or small"...

Comment: A meaningful value can be something i guess that has most of the values centered around it. One way to identify is to take the mean of the list, but the problem is that this is a 2d list, where a and b are not related to each other and are independent variables. And, way too large or way too small can be taken in the same frame i guess: like all the filtered values should not deviate too much from that meaningful value..which I guess in this case is going to be a (n,m) vector?

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point, you can turn your data into a record array:

```
import numpy as np
t = [{'k': 1, 'a': 22, 'b': 59}, {'k': 2, 'a': 21, 'b': 34}, {'k': 3, 'a': 991, 'b': 29}, {'k': 4, 'a': 45, 'b': 11}, {'k': 5, 'a': 211, 'b': 77}, {'k': 6, 'a': 100, 'b': 1024}]
foo = np.core.records.fromrecords([x.values() for x in t], names=t[0].keys())
```

This enables some easier analysis:

```
In [34]: foo.a.mean(), foo.a.std()
Out[34]: (231.66666666666666, 345.81674659018785)

In [35]: foo.b.mean(), foo.b.std()
Out[35]: (205.66666666666666, 366.58590019560518)
```

Perhaps you could look for outliers with a boxplot?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.boxplot([foo.a, foo.b])
pyplot.show()
```

Or, you could find the values within the 90th percentile of the data:

```
In [40]: foo.a[foo.a < np.percentile(foo.a, 90)]
Out[40]: array([ 22,  21,  45, 211, 100])
```

And to select the non-outlier `k` values:

```
outlier_mask = (foo.a < np.percentile(foo.a, 90)) & (foo.b < np.percentile(foo.b, 90))
foo.k[outlier_mask]
```

Of course, how you decide which values are outliers is up to you.

Comment: but how do i retrieve all the k's that are not outliers?

Comment: hey peri, thanks for the approach. Seems quite valid since percentile's concept was pretty much the thing I was after. Let me check a bit more possibilities with it. Thanks.

Comment: Would this work if the outlier was much smaller than the rest?

Comment: @cdhagmann: Nope, you'd need to add more conditions to the `outlier_mask` in that case, but it'll look essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

The code below finds the point that is farthest from the mean, removes it, then it checks the mean again. If removing the point causes the mean to move less than a given tolerance (by way of a percent change from the old mean) then the move is rejected and that old list is returned. Otherwise, the new list is kept and the process continues.

```
t = [{'a': 22, 'b': 59, 'k': 1},
 {'a': 21, 'b': 34, 'k': 2},
 {'a': 991, 'b': 29, 'k': 3},
 {'a': 45, 'b': 11, 'k': 4},
 {'a': 211, 'b': 77, 'k': 5},
 {'a': 100, 'b': 1024, 'k': 6}]

K = [te['k'] for te in t]
A = [te['a'] for te in t]
B = [te['b'] for te in t]

data = zip(K,A,B)

def mean(A):
    return sum(A)/float(len(A))

def max_deviation(A):
    mu = mean(A)
    dev = [(a, abs(a-mu)) for a in A]
    dev.sort(key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
    return dev[0][0]

def remove_outliers(A, tol=.3):
    mu = mean(A)
    A_prime = list(a for a in A if a != max_deviation(A))
    mu_prime = mean(A_prime)
    if abs(mu_prime - mu)/float(mu) > tol:
        return remove_outliers(A_prime, tol)
    else:
        return A

t_prime = [dict(k=k, a=a, b=b) for k, a, b in data 
           if a in remove_outliers(A) and b in remove_outliers(B)]

>>> print t_prime
[{'a': 22, 'b': 59, 'k': 1},
 {'a': 21, 'b': 34, 'k': 2},
 {'a': 45, 'b': 11, 'k': 4}]
```

**EDIT:** This might scale better as it is removing one value instead of creating N-1 values. This would modify the original `A` vector. If you don't want that then the first option would be your best choice or send in a copy to begin with.

```
def remove_outliers(A, tol=.3):
    mu = mean(A)
    out = max_deviation(A)
    A.remove(out)
    mu_prime = mean(A)
    if abs(mu_prime - mu)/float(mu) > tol:
        return remove_outliers(A, tol)
    else:
        A.append(out)
        return A
```

Comment: hey cdhagmann..this seems kool. The point is, will it stay cheaper when dealing with some outrageous outliers and data having a couple of hundred thousand rows? I am hoping it will, but let me try with it. Thanks a lot for your kind answer. :-)

Comment: You could probably help scale up if you used `A.remove(max_deviation(A))` and then add that value back if the change is rejected. I'll add a edit.